# How to do sum of two array string's value and store into another array list in java selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, arraylist

I have 4 Array that store at least 6 value.

```
ArrayList<String> GrossAmt = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> TaxAmt = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> DiscAmt = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> FinalAmt = new ArrayList<String>();

GrossAmt = [ 66.5928,  110.9880,  369.9592,  92.4898,  249.7221,  27.7469] 
TaxAmt = [ 3.8632,  6.4386,  21.4621,  5.3655,  14.4869,  1.6097] 
DiscAmt =[ 2.2137,  3.6895,  12.2984,  3.0746,  8.3014,  0.9224] 
FinalAmt =[ 68.2423,  113.7371,  379.1229,  94.7807,  255.9076,  28.4342]
```

I need to get the result of grossAmt+TaxAmt-DiscAmt and compare with FinalAmt.

```
for(int g = 0; g < GrossAmt.size(); g++){
                int Expected = 0;
                Expected = Integer.valueOf(GrossAmt.get(g)) + Integer.valueOf(TaxAmt.get(g))- Integer.valueOf(DiscAmt.get(g));
                int Actual = Integer.valueOf(FinalAmt.get(g));
                LogFileControl.logInfo(Actual);
                LogFileControl.logInfo(Expected);


             if (Actual == Expected ){

                 LogFileControl.logInfo("Final Amount Passed!");

             }else
             {
                 LogFileControl.logError(("Actual: " + Actual) + " Expected: " + Expected);

             }
```

But i got error for this.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Side note: please use lowercase first letters for your variables :)

Comment: why do you use `List<String>` instead of i.e. `List<BigDecimal>`?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the amounts are in `decimal` whereas you are performing the comparison by converting them into `integer`. I would recommend using `double` literal type for this comparison, e.g.:

```
ArrayList<String> GrossAmt = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> TaxAmt = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> DiscAmt = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> FinalAmt = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int g = 0; g < GrossAmt.size(); g++) {
    double Expected = 0;
    Expected = Double.valueOf(GrossAmt.get(g)) + Double.valueOf(TaxAmt.get(g))
            - Double.valueOf(DiscAmt.get(g));
    double Actual = Double.valueOf(FinalAmt.get(g));
    LogFileControl.logInfo(Actual);
    LogFileControl.logInfo(Expected);

    if (Actual == Expected) {
        LogFileControl.logInfo("Final Amount Passed!");
    } else {
        LogFileControl.logError(("Actual: " + Actual) + " Expected: " + Expected);
    }
}
```

Comment: This still throws a `NumberFormatException`

Comment: @notyou for any particular value? I have tried it just now and was able to parse the values without any `Exception`.

Comment: my apologies, for some reason my IDE missed a `"` and failed miserably, but your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows A and B are two different ArrayLists

```
ArrayList AB = new ArrayList();

AB.addAll(A);
AB.addAll(B);
```